# Mobile menu doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coffeescript

I'm struggling with this issue: 
I'm trying to make a mobile menu on my site using bootstrap and coffeescript. Page is fully responsive and it's working quite well. But as I added a buttons to hide and show menu on mobile view(via coffeescript) buttons don't dissappear when I resize window on desktop view.

```
 $('#button-open').on "click", ->
    $('#wrapper').animate({left: '220px'}, 10)
    $(this).css("display", "none")
    $('#button-close').css("display", "block")
    $('.navbar').slideDown(380)

  $('#button-close').on "click", ->
    $(this).css("display", "none")
    $('#button-open').css("display", "block")
    $('.navbar').slideUp(1)
    $('#wrapper').animate({left: '0px'}, 10)


  if $(window).width() <= 768
     $('#wrapper').css('margin', '0px 0px 0px 0px')
  else
     $('#wrapper').css('margin', '0px 0px 0px 220px') and $('#button-close').css('display', 'none')
```

Don't mind the animation, it works just fine. The problems are: buttons are still visible when window change its size over 768px and wrapper behaves in two ways, depends how I change code: it add another 220px margin on left or stays on margin 0px when I resize window.
My goals are: 
 - buttons are only visible on window with width < 768px
 - wrapper always has 0px left when width < 768 and left 220px when width > 768px.

I tried to write function which dynamically change it, but I failed. If/else statement works, but only when I don't resize window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used coffeescript, but with pure CSS, I would go that way:

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;   // position menu anywhere on your screen
    z-index: 99;       // lay it on top
    left: 100vw;       // position at the right border of the screen -> invisible
    width: 90vw;       // don't forget to set dimensions
    height: 100vh;
    transition: left 0.5s ease-out;  // don't forget multi-browser-support
}

// when adding class "active" to menu, slide it in
#menu.active {
    left: 0;           // slide it in -> visible
}
```

It's now your turn to make it work with coffeescript (or whatever you use)